# How to run a non-exe app without typing its extension in CMD? (i.e environment path variable)

Tags: python, windows, cmd, path, environment-variables

I've got a python application that is located in `O:\Apps\Python\myapp.py`
I added this into my Windows Path `O:\Apps\Python\` so I can run it anywhere with **CMD** as so

```
> myapp someArg1 someArg2
```

But It turns out that I need to type its **extension** (unlike **.exe** files) like this

```
> myapp.py someArg1 someArg2
```

How can I run it by just the name?

Comment: This seems to be more about how to configure Windows file associations and/or `cmd` than about programming, so I suspect you'd be much more likely to get a good answer on Super User.

Comment: CMD and PowerShell look for file extensions in the `PATHEXT` environment vairable. (PowerShell will only run a file if its extension is in this list, which is a needless change from the classic CMD behavior.)  Starting with version 3.5, Python's installer has an option to update the `PATH` and `PATHEXT` environment variables.

Comment: @eryksun This question isn't just about python but Please type your Answer and I'll accept it, I only needed to update the `PATHEXT` variable as you said and add a `;` followed by `.PY` extension to it. now I can run with just the name! :)

Comment: @abarnert I thought about this too but I got an answer here in the comment section so I cannot just ignore it and post somewhere else while I've the answer.

Comment: Surely there are existing questions about `PATHEXT` on superuser.com. Please look for a duplicate there and delete this question.